# Project Euler 23 in Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble on Project Euler Problem 23 - Non-Abundant Sums. My code does not give me the correct answer and I don't know what's wrong with it. If anyone could also help me make it run faster that would be great.

**Original Problem**

A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

**Main Problems of my code**

- Wrong Answer
- Takes way too long to run

**My Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Problem23NonAbundantSums {
    static ArrayList<Integer> abundantNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> sumOfAbundantNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int max = 28123;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getAbundantNumbers();
        int temp = 0, sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < abundantNumbers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < abundantNumbers.size(); j++) {
                temp = (abundantNumbers.get(i) + abundantNumbers.get(j));
                if (temp < max) {
                    sumOfAbundantNumbers.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            if (sumOfAbundantNumbers.contains(i) == false) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((stop - start) + "ms");

    }

    public static boolean isAbundant(int x) {
        int divisorSum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                divisorSum += i;
            }
        }
        if (divisorSum > x) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void getAbundantNumbers() {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (isAbundant(i)) {
                abundantNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:** I am getting 4207994 which is the wrong answer. It takes 79081 ms to run and I would prefer it to be under 1 minute since it says on the Project Euler homepage that all the problems can be solved under 1 minute.

**Edit #2:** I actually found the problem it was in the `if` condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < abundantNumbers.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < abundantNumbers.size(); j++) {
        temp = (abundantNumbers.get(i) + abundantNumbers.get(j));
        if (temp < max) {
            sumOfAbundantNumbers.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

`temp < max` should've been `temp <= max`

Does anyone have ideas on how to optimize it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What answer are you getting? Have you tried using a debugger? And how much faster do you want the code to run (Big O-wise)? How fast is it running right now? Kind of difficult to answer a question without enough context.

Comment: I would make sure it calculates the right answer first. It doesn't matter how long it takes if it''s wrong.

Comment: The solution will take time, it's normal I think, at least mine did. As Peter said, the best is to try with a small number, check if it works before launching the program for a larger number. I'll give you a hint here : I used a list pour the abundant numbers and a list for all the numbers 0 < x < 28124, no other list.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `x + y = z` You know `z` so you can try every `x` and `y which is O(n^2) OR you can try every`x`and calculate`y = z - x`and lookup`y` in a set, this is O(n)

Also you can search for factors up to `x` or you can search for factors up to `Math.sqrt(x)` which gives you two factors `i` and `x / i` assuming these are different.

A more efficient way to store a set of number is to use a BitSet.  This has O(1) lookup.  You can loop through the values preset in a BitSet with

```
for (int j = abundant.nextSetBit(0); j > 0; j = abundant.nextSetBit(j+1)) {
```

If you do all this, it should run in under 100 ms in Java which isn't even enough time for the code to warm up. ;)